# How to find a probability distribution of a variable given a PDF

Tags: probability-distributions

If i have the region: $$W=\left\{ \left( x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R} ^{2}:0\leq y\leq x\leq 1\right\} $$

And the random vector $(X,Y)$ with the following joint PDF:

$$ \begin{equation}
  f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)= \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    c(x^4 + y^2), & \text{if}\ \left( x,y\right) \in W \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} $$

How can i find the probability distribution of the variable $S=(X-Y)$?

Comment: Hint: Convolution over the region $W$.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use this, I have never done Convolutions.

Comment: @probablyme Convolution of what with what? How is this a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that $S$ ranges from $0$ to $1$. Now given any $0\leq s\leq 1$, if we want to write $s=x-y$, then we must have $s\leq x\leq 1$ and $y=x-s$. Thus we should have, for $0\leq s\leq 1$, 
$$
f_S(s)=\int_s^1f_{X,Y}(x,x-s)dx=\int_s^1c(x^4+(x-s)^2)dx
$$

Comment: Sorry but P(S=s)=0 for every s. Please correct your answer acordingly.

Comment: @Did of course, my mistake. Better?

Comment: Much. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First find c using the below

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} c(x^4+y^4)dxdy = 1$$

Then follow the procedure outlined by the other responder, this is not an answer.  Just an aid.

Comment: How do you know from which regions do the integration (from $y$ to $1$ and from $0$ to $1$)?

Comment: You should get that information from the region where the joint probability function is defined,i.e $0\le y\le x\le1$.  For every y from o to 1, x ranges from y to 1.  That is how I formulate my limits to the integral.